# How to pin memory allocated by Marshal.AllocHGlobal() in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, pinvoke, marshalling

How do you pin memory allocated by Marshal.AllocHGlobal()?

My first attempt was the following:

```
int bytes = 10;
IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes);
GCHandle iph = GCHandle.Alloc(ip, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

Although I think this only pins the `IntPtr` and not the block of memory referred to by the `IntPtr`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The memory allocated by `AllocHGlobal` is already pinned. the `IntPtr` that is returned is the address of the pinned location.

UPDATE: To be pedantic you can't actually "pin" the memory allocated by `AllocHGlobal`, to pin something means to tell the Garbage Collector to not move the object in memory. The memory allocated by `AllocHGlobal` is "unmanaged memory" which means it is memory that is not managed by the Garbage Collector.

No process besides the Garbage Collector moves memory around in your program, and the Garbage Collector does not care about unmanaged resources.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying that. The reason I'm asking is because I'm writing code that calls a dll function which takes in an IntPtr and creates and attaches an unmanaged object to that IntPtr. When I then call a different dll function which tries to access that unmanaged object through the IntPtr it throws a 'System.AccessViolationException'. I was thinking that not pinning the unmanaged object had something to do with it. Although it seems like I didn't fully understand pinning yet. I think I'll have to submit another question. Thanks anyway :)