# does intptr address changes by GC?

Tags: c#, pointers, garbage-collection

I created `intptr object` by `marshal. allochglob()`. During the program lifetime, I see an `access violation to a memory exception` while everything seems ok (memory index for copy and... are true).

Does garbage collector or anything else changes its address during the time?

Comment: There is no such method called `marshal. allochglob()` though i am guessing you mean (with the right casing) `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`

Comment: The GarbageCollector only deals with Managed Resources. Those unmanaged pointers are explicitly outside of it's scope and it should not touch them in any way. More likely you just messed up the Pionter Arythmetic. But we can not really tell, as you have shown us 0 lines of code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539292/how-to-pin-memory-allocated-by-marshal-allochglobal-in-c

Comment: thanks. so if I have intptr obj it doesn't release until I release it. even the method that contains it is finished?